# how to integrate crashlytics in Xcode that uses CMS and script for multiple apps

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have the common code in Xcode and a test app identifier. But I generate the ipa for different/many live apps using scripts at admin side and I generate many applications using CMS. So how do I integrate Crashlytics in such case. Currently when I open the fabrics dashboard I just see one app - that is the test app(identifier). Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. In order for an app to be activated on the Fabric dashboard, a build and run of the app is needed. You'll need to build and run each of the apps with Fabric configured within them.

Comment: Thanks Mike. So my build identifier and other stuff is set by cms using scripts. so I integrate fabric to my code and when I run script in cms, it builds the app. so you are saying it should be enough? what if I build a new app with cms using same code? Is fabric associated with a bundle identifier?

Comment: After the build when the ids are set, you would need to run the app under the given bundle id in order for it to activate . API keys are set per organization, not per app.